# Is there a control like the HTML5 Canvas in Cappuccino Web Framework?

Tags: html5-canvas, cappuccino

I'm creating a webapp in Cappuccino, and I need a way to draw shapes (rectangles, images etc) onto a `CPWindow`. Is there any widget/control I can use to do this? Are there any controls like this in other frameworks like Sproutcore? Or do I have to implement my own?

I'd also like to know if there's a way of making shapes draggable [like this](http://rectangleworld.com/demos/OOPDragging/OOPDragging.html)?

Answer (score 1):

In Cappuccino you can perform custom drawing in any view. To do this, override the `drawRect:` method (of anything that inherits from `CPView`, which is pretty much every control). You can either use the CPGraphics tools like [`CPBezierPath`](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/learn/documentation/interface_c_p_bezier_path.html), or you can draw using CoreGraphics with commands like [`CGContextAddPath`](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/learn/documentation/group__coregraphics.html#ga9076c7c9efcc889fa980c49028fca6b8) - to learn more about this latter style of drawing the Apple docs on [Core Graphics for Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-TPXREF101) are helpful. Remember that Cappuccino is based on Objective-C and Cocoa.

Here's an example view that draws a yellow star with a dotted border in a rounded rectangle, sized to fit the current view:

```
@implementation CustomDrawView : CPView
{
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)aRect
{
    [super drawRect:aRect];

    [[CPColor whiteColor] set];
    [[CPBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds] fill];

    var frame =[self bounds],
        shadow = [[CPShadow alloc] init];

    [shadow setShadowColor:[CPColor blackColor]];
    [shadow setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 3)];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius:5];

    //// Rounded Rectangle Drawing
    var roundedRectanglePath = [CPBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 3.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 3.5, CGRectGetWidth(frame) - 7, CGRectGetHeight(frame) - 7) xRadius:7 yRadius:7];
    [[CPColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [roundedRectanglePath setLineWidth:1];
    var roundedRectanglePattern = [5, 1, 1, 1];
    [roundedRectanglePath setLineDash:roundedRectanglePattern phase:0];
    [roundedRectanglePath stroke];

    var starPath = [CPBezierPath bezierPath];
    [starPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.50000 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.20513 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.43029 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.35357 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.31200 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.40445 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.38720 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.54707 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.38381 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.72696 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.50000 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.66667 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.61619 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.72696 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.61280 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.54707 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.68800 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.40445 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath lineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.56971 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.35357 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [starPath closePath];
    [[CPColor yellowColor] setFill];
    [starPath fill];
    [CPGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [shadow set];
    [[CPColor whiteColor] setStroke];
    [starPath setLineWidth:3];
    var starPattern = [5, 1, 5, 1];
    [starPath setLineDash:starPattern phase:2];
    [starPath stroke];
    [CPGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}

@end
```

[image: Image of what the above code renders.]

I extracted this from a larger set of [drawing tests in Cappuccino](https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/blob/master/Tests/Manual/CPGraphicsTest/AppController.j).

Under the hood, Cappuccino will either use a canvas, when available, or VML when necessary (for some versions of IE).

Comment: This is very good, but is there any way to move shapes around with the mouse [like this](http://rectangleworld.com/demos/OOPDragging/OOPDragging.html)?

(sorry for not outlining this in the original question)

Comment: Yes, but how you do it depends a little on how many shapes you want. If you only have a few shapes I would recommend making each shape its own CPView. This makes it easy to react to clicks and drags. On the other hand if you're going to have quite a few, you should use a single CPView which draws all the rectangles and interprets mouse interactions by itself through `mouseDown:`, `mouseUp:` and `mouseDragged:`. Here's an example for how to detect when the mouse cursor is inside of a shape (a path): https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/blob/master/Tests/Manual/CGPath/AppController.j#L68.